# How to cleaning watermark of image using ImageMagic?

Tags: shell, imagemagick

I have a lot of images need clean watermark, so I decide to write a script of shell using ImageMagic, but I do not find any argument can do it.

This is an image sample.

[image]

Comment: You should try to do it first. When you have a specific problem, create the question and some one can help you

Comment: If your trying to add a customized watermark, try some [Compose Usage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#geometry) examples.

Comment: Removing watermarks is not easy, especially if the watermark is similar in color to its background. It may also be illegal to remove watermarks from commercial photographs. If you can change only the watermark into transparency or some different color than used in the image, then you can find tools for inpainting that would do that. OpenCV has such a tool. Also sometimes you can use morphology processing to remove it. For example, see https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=41498#p41498.

Answer (score 0):

I could remove watermark of multiple images with Image Magick using the following command:
`convert original.jpg watermark.jpg -compose Minus -composite -negate result.jpg`

Note that an image of the watermark itself (i.e. a white or transparent background with the same watermark) of the same size is needed.

The command above is subtracting the watermark image from the original, then is negating the result.